# How to use Block Access with specific Block?

Tags: 7, blocks

I am using `block access` module to restrict `block administration` permission. I want to give permission to a role on specific block to edit that block. When I changed the permission firstly it permits only change title and description not body. Second it gives permission on every blocks I added manually.

I only want to allow one single block should be edited by `site editors`. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using a patch and granting input filter permission. Patch is here https://drupal.org/node/1916028#comment-7302100.

Comment: It would be helpful to others, if you mention which patch did you apply to solve this and the input filter permissions used. Also, if the patch works, reporting the same on the issue queue would help getting it in future project releases.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer.